# How to manipulate JavaScript array object data on the basis of its null key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, data-manipulation

I have data as below:

```
let activityList = [
{
"2-createdAt": "2019-12-27T13:11:04.300+0000",
"2-modifiedAt": "2020-01-02T13:28:18.877+0000",
"2-createdBy": "admin_tna",
"2-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna",
"2-id": 2,
"2-name": "Activity 2",
"2-serialNo": 543,
"2-notify": "No",
"2-department": {createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2,},
"2-subActivityList": [{}],
"2-departmentId": 2,
"2-cLevel": "false",
"20-createdAt": "2020-01-09T08:44:19.697+0000",
"20-modifiedAt": "2020-01-09T08:44:19.697+0000",
"20-createdBy": "admin_tna",
"20-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna",
"20-id": 20,
"20-name": "Activity 3",
"20-serialNo": 8,
"20-notify": null,
"20-department": {createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:03:09.485+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:14.402+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 1,},
"20-subActivityList": (3) [{}, {}, {}],
"20-departmentId": 1,
"20-cLevel": true,
"21-createdAt": "2020-01-09T08:48:16.282+0000",
"21-modifiedAt": "2020-01-09T08:48:16.282+0000",
"21-createdBy": "admin_tna",
"21-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna",
"21-id": 21,
"21-name": "Activity 1",
"21-serialNo": 8,
"21-notify": null,
"21-department": {createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2,},
"21-subActivityList": (2),
"21-departmentId": 2,
"21-cLevel": true,
"buyerId": 2,
"name": "ss",
"tnaType": "Forward",
"2-leadTimeNormal": 8,
"2-leadTimeOptimal": 4,
"2-timeFrom": "O"}
]
```

As you can see, I have `leadTimeNormal` and `leadTimeOptimal` data only for `id 2` read as `2-leadTimeNormal: 8, 2-leadTimeOptimal: 4,`

So, I want new List of Object as below:

```
let newActivity = [{
        "2-createdAt": "2019-12-27T13:11:04.300+0000",
        "2-modifiedAt": "2020-01-02T13:28:18.877+0000",
        "2-createdBy": "admin_tna",
        "2-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna",
        "2-id": 2,
        "2-name": "Activity 2",
        "2-serialNo": 543,
        "2-notify": "No",
        "2-department": {createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2,},
        "2-subActivityList": [{}],
        "2-departmentId": 2,
        "2-cLevel": "false",
    "2-leadTimeNormal": 8,
        "2-leadTimeOptimal": 4,
        "2-timeFrom": "O"
    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could likely be made shorter but it is a start

```js
let activityList = [{ "2-createdAt": "2019-12-27T13:11:04.300+0000", "2-modifiedAt": "2020-01-02T13:28:18.877+0000", "2-createdBy": "admin_tna", "2-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna", "2-id": 2, "2-name": "Activity 2", "2-serialNo": 543, "2-notify": "No", "2-department": { createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2, }, "2-subActivityList": [{}], "2-departmentId": 2, "2-cLevel": "false", "20-createdAt": "2020-01-09T08:44:19.697+0000", "20-modifiedAt": "2020-01-09T08:44:19.697+0000", "20-createdBy": "admin_tna", "20-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna", "20-id": 20, "20-name": "Activity 3", "20-serialNo": 8, "20-notify": null, "20-department": { createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:03:09.485+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:14.402+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 1, }, "20-subActivityList": (3)[{}, {}, {}], "20-departmentId": 1, "20-cLevel": true, "21-createdAt": "2020-01-09T08:48:16.282+0000", "21-modifiedAt": "2020-01-09T08:48:16.282+0000", "21-createdBy": "admin_tna", "21-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna", "21-id": 21, "21-name": "Activity 1", "21-serialNo": 8, "21-notify": null, "21-department": { createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2, }, "21-subActivityList": (2), "21-departmentId": 2, "21-cLevel": true, "buyerId": 2, "name": "ss", "tnaType": "Forward", "2-leadTimeNormal": 8, "2-leadTimeOptimal": 4, "2-timeFrom": "O" }]

const keys = Object.keys(activityList[0]);
const matches = JSON.stringify(keys).matchAll(/"(\d+-)leadTime/g);
prefix = [];
for (const match of matches) {
  if (prefix.indexOf(match[1]) === -1) prefix.push(match[1])
}  
const newObject = {}
keys.forEach(k => { 
  if (prefix.indexOf(k.split("-")[0]+"-") === 0) newObject[k] = activityList[0][k]
})
console.log(newObject)
```

---

Here is a version sugested by [Mickael B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9434800/mickael-b) using reduce. It is not testing the existence of the key but that could be added

```js
let activityList = [{ "2-createdAt": "2019-12-27T13:11:04.300+0000", "2-modifiedAt": "2020-01-02T13:28:18.877+0000", "2-createdBy": "admin_tna", "2-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna", "2-id": 2, "2-name": "Activity 2", "2-serialNo": 543, "2-notify": "No", "2-department": { createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2, }, "2-subActivityList": [{}], "2-departmentId": 2, "2-cLevel": "false", "20-createdAt": "2020-01-09T08:44:19.697+0000", "20-modifiedAt": "2020-01-09T08:44:19.697+0000", "20-createdBy": "admin_tna", "20-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna", "20-id": 20, "20-name": "Activity 3", "20-serialNo": 8, "20-notify": null, "20-department": { createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:03:09.485+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:14.402+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 1, }, "20-subActivityList": (3)[{}, {}, {}], "20-departmentId": 1, "20-cLevel": true, "21-createdAt": "2020-01-09T08:48:16.282+0000", "21-modifiedAt": "2020-01-09T08:48:16.282+0000", "21-createdBy": "admin_tna", "21-lastModifiedBy": "admin_tna", "21-id": 21, "21-name": "Activity 1", "21-serialNo": 8, "21-notify": null, "21-department": { createdAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", modifiedAt: "2019-12-26T12:26:37.752+0000", createdBy: "admin_tna", lastModifiedBy: "admin_tna", id: 2, }, "21-subActivityList": (2), "21-departmentId": 2, "21-cLevel": true, "buyerId": 2, "name": "ss", "tnaType": "Forward", "2-leadTimeNormal": 8, "2-leadTimeOptimal": 4, "2-timeFrom": "O" }]

const result = Object.entries(activityList[0]) // List all entries
  .filter(([e, v]) => e.split('-')[0] === '2') // Filter those who start with '2'
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { // Populate a new object
    acc[key] = value
    return acc
  }, {})
console.log(result)
```